# OID type in regular postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I have a PL/pgSQL function, which fetch data from `pg_catalog.pg_constraint` table to generate restore FK statements like: `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOREIGN KEY (column) REFERENCES table_name (column);`.
Firstly I find oid of the table, then I put that table oid into variable `table_oid OID;` and make some stuff with it.

My question is.. Is it OK to use OID type variable inside function or I should better use BIGINT or something?

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func()
   RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
   row RECORD;
   table_oid OID; --> Is it OK or I should use BIGINT?
BEGIN
   ...
   SELECT pg_class.oid
      FROM pg_catalog.pg_class
      INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
      WHERE pg_class.relname = row.table_name
      AND pg_namespace.nspname = row.schema_name INTO table_oid;
   ...
   SELECT nspname, relname, 'ALTER TABLE '||nspname||'.'||relname||' ADD CONSTRAINT '||conname||' '||pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(pg_constraint.oid)||';'
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint
   INNER JOIN pg_class ON conrelid = pg_class.oid
   INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
   WHERE confrelid = table_oid   --> I use this variable here
   OR conrelid = table_oid       --> ...and here
   AND contype = 'f';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Why would it *not* be ok to use `oid`? It is the type that you want to use, it is the type that all the values you're dealing with has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using `oid` like any other data type.

The only thing that you should keep in mind is that the OIDs that PostgreSQL uses internally to identify objects like tables are subject to change during an upgrade or restore from a dump. So you should not use `oid`s to permanently store references to system objects.

The same applies to the `ref*` types, which are OIDs under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! Sure I do not plan to store that values permanently as a constants. When database is restored (from dump) or upgraded I create and execute functions from the scratch and the ```oid```s should change too.